# syntax error "transparent" is not a color for 'ie-hex-str'

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, compass-sass

I'm using compass and in In below code I want to replace `#fff` with transparency for `@include filter-gradient`. but there is no hex code for transparency so i used `transparent` but it's giving error `syntax error "transparent" is not a color for 'ie-hex-str'`

```
@include filter-gradient(#f3f2f3, transparent, vertical);
$experimental-support-for-svg: true;
@include background-image(linear-gradient(top, #f3f2f3 0%,#eaeae9 68%,#cfcece 70%,transparent 73%,transparent 100%));
```

Comment: I really dont know anything about Compass but did you look at their [rgba function](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#rgba-instance_method)

Comment: @MarkHall ok but IE 8 and lower doesn't support rgba

Comment: Okay, It was just a shot in the dark

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the `filter-gradient` mixin is expecting a specific color format:  3 or 6 digit hex or rgb.  So you want to pass it a transparent color:

```
@include filter-gradient(#f3f2f3, transparentize(white, 1), vertical);
```